# Is it possible to receive broadcast when app is closed

Tags: android, flutter

I tried to code the push notification feature for my flutter plugin. There is a android service will not be killed when app is closed, and I have not setup the flutter background isolate, if this service receive a message, is it possible to send this message directly through broadcast to the dart side?